# Extjs is passing my cfc a json string that I can not read

Tags: json, extjs, coldfusion, extjs4, coldfusion-9

I am playing with the [ExtJs4 cartracker application](http://existdissolve.com/tag/extjs4/) written by existdisolve. I was able to change his queries from rest requests to ajax requests. I also modified the api calls to use ajax to make ajax requests for updates.

I am not getting form or url data passed to my cfc. Instead, in firebug I see JSON passed. I am confused if it is not passed in the form or the url, how is this passed and how do I get to the data? I have tried deserialized the form and url and dumping these after the deserialize and I am told that it is not json.

Where would I find the json?
I am not allowed to post a picture. But it looks like this in the xhr window:

```
JSON
   Active     true
   ColorID    null
   Shortname  red
   Longname   Blood Red
```

So if it is being passed why can I not get to it?

**Edit:**
@existdissolve - I replaced the rest.js with ajax.js which looks like this:

```
     /**
    * Abstract REST proxy 
    */
    Ext.define('CarTracker6.proxy.Ajax', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    alias: 'proxy.baseajax',
    /*format: 'json',*/
    limitParam: 'max',
    startParam: 'offset',
    sortParam: 'sortorder',
    writer : { 
    type : 'ajax',
    encode : false,
    writeAllFields : true,
    root : 'data',
    allowSingle : true,
    batch : false,
    method: 'post',
params: { record: 'record' },
    writeRecords : function(request, data) {
    request.jsonData = data;
return request;
    }
 },

reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'data',
    totalProperty: 'count'
},
    api: {
        read: 'api/option/colors.cfc?method=getcolors',
        create: 'api/option/colors.cfc?method=addcolors',
        update: 'api/option/colors.cfc?method=updatecolors',
        destroy: 'api/option/colors.cfc?method=deletecolors'
    }
});
```

My read works perfectly and I can call the correct cfcs for colors, statuses, etc. and retrieve the requisite data. I am looking to pass parameters to the CFCs and that is not working.

Comment: What does your proxy and writer config look like?

Comment: A few things: 1.) Why are you overwriting writeRecords() in your writer? 2.) Since you've specified a "root" in your writer, you should expect to see a "data" key in your form that contains the serialized JSON of the model instance(s) that you're persisting. You should be able to deserialize that and get an object that CF can use.

Comment: existdissolve, Your comments tell me I need to go back to the sencha docs and do a bit more reading. I thought I could replace the rest calls with ajax calls. Obviously not. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to replace them...its just a matter of configuration

Comment: existdissolve, i removed the writer as I see they were not necessary. I looked at the ajax proxy again and read skittle's article dealing with overriding proxies. What I want to do is take what is being sent as request.jsonData and change it to request.params. I tried this:

  buildRequest: function(operation) { 
        var request = this.callParent(arguments); 
   request.params = request.jsonData;
  request.jsonData = {};  
        return request; 
    }, 
     getMethod: function(request) { 
        return 'POST'; 
    } ,

});

Answer (score 0):

see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-encode:

if the encode property of your writer is set to false, all data is sent as raw post body. Instead, you can use

```
encode: true, 
root: 'data', // must be set if encode is true
```